# Multiplicar dos campos de tablas diferentes y guardar resultado en otro campo laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo dos tablas:

**platos**

**ordenPlato**

están relacionadas así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la tabla de **platos** esta el 'valor' o precio que deseo multiplicar por el campo 'cantidad' que esta en mi otra tabla **ordenPlato**, y que el resultado se almacene en el campo 'valor' de la tabla **ordenPlato**

tengo entendido que en php se hace con un inner join, pero estoy usando eloquen y laravel y se que se haría mas limpio utilizando estas herramientas que php puro, les pongo las migraciones para que no estar tan perdidos.

plato migración

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('platos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->char('nombre',50);
            $table->double('valor', 8, 2);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

plato modelo

```
class Plato extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['nombre', 'valor'];


    public function platoingrediente() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\PlatoIngrediente');
}


}
```

ordenPlato migracion

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('ordenPlato', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('orden_id');
            $table->foreign('orden_id')->references('id')->on('orden');
            $table->unsignedInteger('plato_id');
            $table->foreign('plato_id')->references('id')->on('platos');
            $table->integer('cantidad');
            $table->double('valor', 8, 2);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

ordenPlato modelo

```
class OrdenPlato extends Model
{
  public $table = "ordenPlato";
  protected $fillable = ['orden_id','plato_id','cantidad','valor'];

  public function orden(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Orden');
  }

  public function plato(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Plato');
  }
```

ordenPlato controller

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
      $validatedData = $request->validate([
          'cantidad' => 'required|numeric|digits_between:1,3',
          'plato_id' => 'required|max:50',
          'orden_id' => 'required|max:50|unique:ordenPlato'
      ]);

      $ordenplato = OrdenPlato::create($validatedData);
      return redirect('/ordenplato/create')->with('success',
      'La orden se guardó correctamente en la base de datos,
      puedes seguir agregando más platos si deseas..');
    }
```

Comment: @Shaz Revisa esto por acá compañero, haber si me das una mano de nuevo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que haces no es la forma correcta de hacer un pedido, el costo que indicas ya debería de ser calculado en el lado del cliente es decir mostrar el total de un pedido, esto por usabilidad y navegabilidad de tu sistema.

Pero en tu caso lo que haría es agregar algunas lineas código en el modelo OrdenPlato:

```
use App\Plato;//importo la clase plato

class OrdenPlato extends Model
{
  public $table = "ordenPlato";
  protected $fillable = ['orden_id','plato_id','cantidad','valor'];

  public function orden(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Orden');
  }

  public function plato(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Plato');
  }
  public static function boot(){
    parent::boot();
    self::creating(function($obj){
      $plato=Plato::find($obj->plato_id);
      $obj->valor=$obj->cantidad * $plato->valor;
    });
  }
}
```

La función `creating` se ejecutara antes de guardar tu modelo, `$obj` es el objeto que esta siendo tratado.Entonces en tu controlador no haces ninguna alteracion y ya deberia de haberse calculado el valor de `valor`.

Mas información sobre dichos eventos en https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#events , NO se en que versión de laravel trabajas así que te deje el primero que encontré.

Comment: me da error de syntax: syntax error, unexpected 'boot' (T_STRING), expecting '('"

Comment: @BrayanR, vuelve a intentarlo, ya edite la respuesta

Comment: Justo lo que quería, perfecto.